# How should I proceed after running the collect command?

Tags: sql, oracle, casting, oracle11g, collect

Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production.

I have a table in the below format.

```
Number  User  Value
-------------------
1       A     25
1       B     28
2       C     30
2       D     35
```

This is what I want:

```
Number  User  Value
-------------------
1       A,B   25,28
2       C,D   30,35
```

I tried using a Listagg but it gives me `ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long.`

This was the listagg command:

```
  SELECT "Number",
         LISTAGG ("user", ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "user") "user",
         LISTAGG ("value", ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "user") VALUE
    FROM table
GROUP BY "Number";
```

I cant create type as I dont have privileges. In one of the other similar questions, someone suggested using collect. So using this:

```
  SELECT number, CAST (COLLECT (USER) AS SYS.DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY)
    FROM emp
GROUP BY number;
```

I dont know where to go from here. When I run this query, I get this column:

```
CAST(COLLECT(USER)ASSYS 
-----------------------
COLLECTION  
COLLECTION  
COLLECTION
```

As you can see my sql knowledge is very minimal. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the xmlagg approach:

```
rtrim(xmlagg(xmlelement(e, name1 || ',')).extract('//text()').getclobval(), ',')
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5f704c/7)